# Released app says compatible with iPad in the app store but was compiled for iPhone only

Tags: ios, xcode

I just released my first app for deployment target I had iOS 7.0 and devices set to iPhone. However when I view my app in the store it says: compatible with iPhone, **iPad** and iPod Touch. Could anyone tell me why this might be happening? It shouldn't say that right?

Comment: By default all apps have to be runnable on iPad, to be approved. If you target app only for iphone, it won't show up in appstore search results when browsing this with iPad... Or so I understand it..

Answer (score 1):

It just means it you can also run it on iPad. However since the app has been targeted for iPhone only it will be scaled and centered on the iPad screen to fit an iPhone screen size (leaving an empty space around)

Comment: Personally, I feel this is nice.